# T-SQL Query 'Where' based on an If Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Hello I have following exert from a SQL server stored procedure:

```
SET @GenderToSearchBy =
        CASE 
            When @Gender IS NOT NULL And @Gender='M' THEN @MaleID
            When @Gender IS NOT NULL And @Gender='F' Then @FemaleID
            Else NULL
        End

SELECT FRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,ID_NUMB,GRDE_DSCN,
GEND_ID FROM #TEMP_STUD WHERE GEND_ID=@GenderToSearchBy
```

Now, I want this to work that if `@Gender` is NULL or not equal to `M` or `F` then search both genders, meaning that `WHERE` isn't required, is there any way to do that without writing 2 separate queries inside a `CASE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `COALESCE`

```
WHERE GEND_ID = COALESCE(@GenderToSearchBy, GEND_ID)
```

or `ISNULL`

```
WHERE GEND_ID = ISNULL(@GenderToSearchBy, GEND_ID)
```

- [COALESCE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)
- [ISNULL()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

Comment: If @Gender can be not null but something other than M or F then this will not help.

Comment: @cdonner are you sure with that?

Comment: This part of his question is the key "is NULL or not equal to M or F then search both genders"

Comment: @cdonner well if you analyze the `SET` statement. anything that is `NULL or not M or F` will be equal to `NULL`, see `CASE WHEN....Else NULL`. if you try to enter `X` for `@gender`, do you think the value of `SET @GenderToSearchBy` is `X`? **NO, it's NULL**.